# Troubleshooting no data displaying

Tags: angular

I have a simple project I am working on, which compiles and doesn't show any errors but is not returning any data when run. Where should I start to figure out why it is not displaying any data? I am quite new to web development and Angular BTW...

The routing works but all I get is the two "headers" in the html file 9 times, no actual data. I know the API works from testing in postman.

thoughts and tips are greatly appreciated.

```
Service.ts

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const apiUrl = 'http://webserver/API/datafile';

export interface Datafile {
  Id?: string;
  DataFileLayoutID: number;
  HasScheduleA: string;
  ShowInEligibilityViewer: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class DatafileLoader {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getList(): Observable<Datafile[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<Datafile[]>(apiUrl)
      .pipe(map(longList => longList.slice(0, 9)));
  }

  getDetails(datafileId: string): Observable<Datafile> {
    return this.http.get<Datafile>(
      `${apiUrl}/${datafileId}`
    );
  }
}

list.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Datafile, DatafileLoader } from '../datafile-loader.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'edx-datafile-list',
  templateUrl: './datafile-list.component.html'
})
export class DatafileListComponent {
  list: Observable<Datafile[]>;

  constructor(loader: DatafileLoader) {
    this.list = loader.getList();
  }
}


html

<section class="card">
  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="card-title">Select Datafile</div>
    <ul class="collection">
      <li
        class="collection-item"
        *ngFor="let l of list | async"
      >
      DatafileID: {{ l.Id }} LayoutId: {{ l.DataFileLayoutID}}
      </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Edited with console output from the addition of the tap function…

Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
ContentScript.js:112 Exception in onResRdy: TypeError: Cannot read property 'htmlRes' of undefined
datafile-loader.service.ts:20 (9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {id: "00000035-0075-0000-0000-000000000000", createdByID: "SB25", createdDate: "2019-06-20T19:53:44.26", modifiedByID: "SB25", modifiedDate: "2019-06-20T19:53:44.26", …}1: {id: "00000035-0066-0000-0000-000000000000", createdByID: "SB25", createdDate: "2019-02-21T20:19:20.08", modifiedByID: "SB25", modifiedDate: "2019-02-21T20:19:20.08", …}2: {id: "00000035-0072-0000-0000-000000000000", createdByID: "SB25", createdDate: "2019-02-21T20:19:20.08", modifiedByID: "SB25", modifiedDate: "2019-02-21T20:19:20.08", …}3: {id: "00000035-0070-0000-0000-000000000000", createdByID: "SB25", createdDate: "2019-02-21T20:19:20.08", modifiedByID: "SB25", modifiedDate: "2019-02-21T20:19:20.08", …}4: {id: "00000035-0073-0000-0000-000000000000", createdByID: "SB25", createdDate: "2019-02-21T20:19:20.093", modifiedByID: "SB25", modifiedDate: "2019-02-21T20:19:20.093", …}5: {id: "00000035-0055-0000-0000-000000000000", createdByID: "SB25", createdDate: "2019-02-21T20:19:20.08", modifiedByID: "SB25", modifiedDate: "2019-02-21T20:19:20.08", …}6: {id: "00000035-0071-0000-0000-000000000000", createdByID: "SB25", createdDate: "2019-02-21T20:19:20.08", modifiedByID: "SB25", modifiedDate: "2019-02-21T20:19:20.08", …}7: {id: "00000035-0067-0000-0000-000000000000", createdByID: "SB25", createdDate: "2019-02-21T20:19:20.08", modifiedByID: "SB25", modifiedDate: "2019-02-21T20:19:20.08", …}8: {id: "00000035-0074-0000-0000-000000000000", createdByID: "SB25", createdDate: "2019-05-02T19:42:51.617", modifiedByID: "SB25", modifiedDate: "2019-05-02T19:42:51.617", …}length: 9__proto__: Array(0)
client:52 [WDS] Live Reloading enabled.

It certainly seems to be pulling the data from the API and it is clearly my very weak typescript skills that is the issue in the displaying of the data.

Comment: It would be great if you reproduced your app in StackBlitz (or sample) to let us see the full behaviour

Comment: If you log the response objects, do they have the proper format? `return this.http.get<Datafile[]>(apiUrl).pipe(map(longList => longList.slice(0, 9)), tap(results => console.log(results)));` (and can you show us an example response?)

Comment: *Where should I start to figure out why it is not displaying any data*: in your browser dev tools. Add logging statements to your code to know what happens, which data is sent, returned, etc. And/or use the debugger.

Comment: You **do** have an error: `Exception in onResRdy: TypeError: Cannot read property 'htmlRes' of undefined datafile-loader.service.ts:20`. And as the logs show, your objects don't have any property named `Id`, and don't have seem to any property named `DataFileLayoutID` (logging the arrays stringified to JSON would allow seeing everything in the logs). JavaScript iscase-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your data does not match. We are not seeing all the properties in your data, but what we can see, is that you are trying to display the id with `l.Id`, with capital `i`. But your data contains property `id`. This matters. You need to change your model to match your data, and you can display the id with:

```html
<li *ngFor="let l of list | async">
  DatafileID: {{ l.id }}
</li>
```